# Prove $(a_1 + a_2 + a_3)^2 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + 2(a_1a_2+ a_2a_3 + a_1a_3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I wish to find a proof for this equality:

$(a_1 + a_2 + a_3)^2 = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + 2(a_1a_2+ a_2a_3 + a_1a_3)$

But then I realized there exists a more general version:

$(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k)^2 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^2 + 2 \sum\limits_{1 \leq k < j \leq m} a_ka_j$

Does anyone have a proof for the more general version of this equality?

Comment: I think proving by induction would be straightforward. Also in the last summation sign it should be $n$ instead of $m$.

Comment: Why not use binomial twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma: Lagrange identity** Let $x=(x_1,...,x_n),y=(y_1,...,y_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\|x\|^2 \|y\|^2-\langle x,y\rangle^2=\sum_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2$.

Before prove this formula, note that it means

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\sum_{j=1}^ny_i^2=\sum_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\right)^2.$$

Thus, if we take $y_i=1$, then

$$n\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2=\sum_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2\\
=\sum_{i<j}(x_i^2+x_j^2)-2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2\\=(n-1)\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-2\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2$$ from your equality  follows.

**Proof of Lagrange Identity**

$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\sum_{j=1}^ny_i^2-\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\right)^2\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\sum_{j=1}^ny_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\sum_{j=1}^nx_jy_j\\
&=&\sum_{i,j=1}x_i^2y_j^2-\sum_{i,j=1}x_iy_ix_jy_j\\
&=&\sum_{i<j}x_i^2y_j^2+\sum_{i=1}x_i^2y_i^2+\sum_{i>j}x_j^2y_i^2\\
&&-\sum_{i<j}x_iy_ix_jy_j-\sum_{i=j}x_iy_ix_jy_j-\sum_{i>j}x_iy_ix_jy_j\\
&=&\sum_{i<j}x_i^2y_j^2+\sum_{i>j}x_j^2y_i^2-2\sum_{i<j}x_iy_ix_jy_j\\
&=&\sum_{i<j}x_i^2y_j^2-2x_iy_ix_jy_j+x_jy_i^2\\
&=&\sum_{i<j}(x_iy_j-x_jy_i)^2
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: This seems like heavy overkill. A simple inductive proof would do

Comment: Indeed there is a simpler proof by simmetry. On the other hand, if you know Lagrange Indentity, then the OP is trivial as I show

Answer (score 0):

Both describe the quadratic form defined by $A^T G A,$ where the column vector
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
\vdots \\
a_n,
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and $G$ is the square matrix with all entries equal to $1.$